# Error: Name can't be blank; using scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

It's a very simple problem. I try to save a comment, but I get the error in the title. This just occurs when I use scope to put my files in a new folder.

### _form

```
<%= form_for(@comment, url: comments_path) do |f| %>

 <%= f.label :name %><br>
 <%= f.text_field :name %>
 ...

<%= submit_tag 'Submit', :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>

<% end %>
```

### routes

```
scope module: 'admin' do 
  resources :comments
end
```

### controller

```
module Admin
 class CommentsController < ApplicationController
...

def comment_params
  params.require(:comment).permit(:name...) if params[:comment]
end

 end
end
```

### model

```
module Admin
  class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base

    validates :name, presence: true
    ...
 end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update the `comment_params` method as below:

```
def comment_params
  params.require(:admin_comment).permit(:name...)
end
```

If you notice the `params` hash generated(in server log) upon submission of the form, you'll notice that the generated hash key is `:admin_comment` and not `:comment` which is due to scoping `comment` under `admin`.